# Solution for 2D steady-state heat equation for rectangular plate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation, laplace-method

Considering $∇^2U=0$ for a rectangular plate with a maximum length of $a$ and width of $b$ respectively.

Following are the boundary conditions:
for $y=0$
$U_y = 0$ within $0<x<a/2$ and $U = -V_o$ within $a/2<x<a$
for $y=b$
$U = V_0$ within $0<x<a/2$ and $U_y = 0$ within $a/2<x<a$
for $x = 0$ & $x = a$, $U_x = 0$

$Vo$ is a constant. What is the solution$(U(x,y))$?
The mid-plane boundary condition will be when the rectangle will split along $y$ (At $x = a/2$)?
What will be the general solution to assume in this case?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you want an analytic solution or do you want a way to **program it** ? In the first case, the fact that there are discontinuities on the boundary conditions make it difficult.

Comment: @JeanMarie I want an analytical solution. I am trying to solve the problem but I am stuck at the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos for the references. That is really helpful. I have edited the question as per the guide and tried to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Solve the equation in the separate regions, and see if you can unite them nicely at the boundary.